# Prove that $\det (A)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix that
$$a_{ii} >\sum_{j=1\atop j\neq i}^{n} \mid a_{ij}\mid \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$$

To prove the matrix A satisfies $\det (A)>0$.

I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Answer (score 2):

If $\det(A)\leq 0$ then there exists $\lambda\leq 0,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $Ax=\lambda x$.

Select $|x_i|=\max_{j\in[n]}|x_j|$ then $\lambda x_i=(Ax)_i=\sum_{j\in[n]}a_{ij}x_j$

\begin{align*}
|(\lambda -a_{ii})x_i|&=|\lambda -a_{ii}||x_i|\geq |a_{ii}||x_i|
\\&>\sum_{j\in[n],j\neq i}|a_{ij}||x_i|
\geq\sum_{j\in[n],j\neq i}|a_{ij}x_j|
\geq|\sum_{j\in[n],j\neq i}a_{ij}x_j|
\end{align*}

It is contradict to $(\lambda -a_{ii})x_i=\sum_{j\in[n],j\neq i}a_{ij}x_j$

Comment: We suppose $\lambda\leq 0$, and in the problem we have $a_{ii}>0$. Then $|\lambda-a_{ii}|=a_{ii}-\lambda\geq a_{ii}=|a_{ii}|$

Comment: Oups, I wrote the reason, but I got the inequality the wrong way. You are right!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was wondering if there is an answer, using the elementary row operations to solve the problem. Anyway, it's a perfect answer! Thank you~